# How to reload jpanel each time it is called?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have some jpanel in my project. it is called once in the beginning and does not call after it due to which content on those jpanel does not update.

Comment: Please explain more why you need to update the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods when you need to update it.

```
panel.revalidate(); 
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: tried the above code but didn't work